# Java removing clients from a file

Tags: java, arrays, file, client

this code can find the client but cant remove it. client name - "rafael"
i just cant remove the client and i dont know why, i tried some codes but didnt work, can you guys help me?

//this delets clients

```
public void EliminarUtilizador(){
              ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> dados = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
            dados = _ficheiro.lerDados();
            // the line is an array that haves date stored on the file
            //0-nome 1-pass ...
            for(ArrayList<String> linha : dados){
                Utilizador a = new Utilizador(linha);
                if("Rafael".equals(linha.get(0))){
                    System.out.println("Client found");

                }
            }  
          }


    ----------------------
    //This reads the file

      public ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> lerDados(){
            ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> dados = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
            Scanner s;
            try{
            s = new Scanner(new File(nomeFicheiro));
            }catch(FileNotFoundException e){
                return dados;
            }
            String dado;

            while(s.hasNextLine()){
                dado = s.nextLine();
                dados.add(new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(dado.split(","))));
            }
            s.close();
            return dados;
        }
```

Comment: this has nothing to do with javascript as javascript is to java as carpet is to car

Comment: @JaromandaX - So JavaScript is something you might find inside Java?

Comment: @nnnnnn - damn your logic :p why did you never point that out the 100's of times I've read other people post it :p